# Portable Class Library and .NET Framework 4.6.x

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library

**Is it possible to create a portable class library that targets .NET Framework 4.6 or 4.6.1?**

We are converting a number of our C# .NET 4.6.1 projects to Portable Class Library (PCL) and in that process had to set `TargetFrameworkVersion` to `v4.5` in order to fix the following error during load of the projects:

> error  : The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Portable\v4.6.1\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

The Portable folder does not contain a `4.6.1` subfolder, but does however contain a `4.6` subfolder. Unfortunately, when trying `4.6` as `TargetFrameworkVersion`, the following dialog appears with a download link that ends on www.msn.com:

[image: Review Solution Action dialog]

In the project properties under Targeting it is possible to select `.NET Framework 4.6` but that just produces the following message:

> The following will be automatically targeted because they support the same set of portable APIs: .NET Framework 4.5

[image: Change Targets dialog]

Comment: Not till .NET Standard 2.0/vNext : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library You can track the changes being made via : https://github.com/dotnet/standard/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.Net Standard 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/08/14/announcing-net-standard-2-0/) has now been released enabling us to avoid using PCL thereby being limited to the capabilities in the .NET Framework 4.5.

Support matrix can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md).